# jQuery: .append() + replace text with random number in <textarea>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

**Simplified Introduction:** I am trying to append text to a already populated  element, without messing with it, in which that appended text is also a random number each page load.

**The first issue:** I've figured out how to append text with in a  element, but I  can't seem to figure out how to change the appended text to a random number in a  element. I've figured a few ways to do it within elements that are standard  or  elements, but appending elements to a  doesn't work correctly from my understanding.

HTML:

```
<textarea id="status">test https://twitter.com/test</textarea>
```

Tested page URL:
[https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?......](https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=&text=test%20https://twitter.com/test&original_referer=)

.Append() code used:

```
function callback() {
    $("#status").append(' aaa');
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setTimeout(callback, 100);
});
```

**The second issue:** So I've found a better bit of code that I would have used in a situation that isn't  based (**in link below**), its probably the best solution I seek,  however it's function runs on click, I would like this to run every time the page loads; replacing appending text to a random number, not based on a click event method.

What I would like to happen:

```
<textarea id="status">test https://twitter.com/test 798</textarea>
```

Footnote: the text excluding the random number between "> … 798<", is assumed to be random with what the user types.

[The sandbox Fiddle with code](http://jsfiddle.net/h5u5b1wk/1/)

Comment: Your code sample is incomplete - it makes reference to an element with ID `ccode` that doesn't exist.

Comment: As mentioned, it's a sample code. I am completely unsure how to turn that sample code into a working one for the purposes I seek. I've successfully tried other versions on non 'textarea' elements, but ideally, the one I provided would be suited best if it  wasn't for the requiring to run on .click() function.

Comment: Unfortunately sample code isn't useful to potential answerers unless it works, otherwise it's very difficult to discern what exactly the code should be doing.

Comment: Do you really need the random number to be between 100 and 999 ?

Comment: i found this too http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tnPTu/

Comment: yes, its to fool twitters automated systems for activists who tweetstorm. This is just the beginning of what im working on

Comment: it can contain numbers or letters,  doesn't have to be limited to 3 spaces

Comment: What? number an letter and not limited to 3 chars ? Hey... Can you define what you need clearly? A muffin and a coffe with it?

Comment: I only said it  doesn't have to be limited to 3 in respect to other coders who may find difficulties conforming to only 3, but Nick gave a working example to what I needed, I greatly appreciate everyones help and tried my best to explain my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to append a random number to pre-existing text in a `textarea`, the following code will work:

```
<textarea id="test">Existing text</textarea>
<script>
    var minNumber = 100;
    var maxNumber = 999;

    $(function() {
        $("#test").append(" " + randomNumber(minNumber, maxNumber));
    });

    function randomNumber(min, max) {
        var number = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min));
        return number;
    }
</script>
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fzfmevhk/

Comment: im curious, any way to use "setInterval(function()" with this?

Answer (score 0):

if you all you want to do is add a random number to `textarea` on page load you can do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   function callback() {
     $("#status").append(randomNumberFromRange(100, 999));
   };

   function randomNumberFromRange(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
   }
   callback();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="status">test https://twitter.com/test</textarea>
```

Comment: this completes my answer, thanks so much: $("#status").append(' ' + randomNumberFromRange(100, 999));

Comment: im curious, any way to use "setInterval(function()" with this?

Comment: you can use `setInterval` but what do you wanna do with it?

Answer (score 0):

You will need some math methods like [`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) and [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)...
You could use them that way.

Notice the `while` loop which ensures a random number between 100 and 999.
;)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var randomNumber = 0;
  while(randomNumber<101 || randomNumber>1000){     // This while loop ensures a number within ranges
    randomNumber = parseInt(Math.random()*1000);
  }
  $("#status").append(" "+randomNumber);
});
```

```css
textarea{
  width:20em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="status">test https://twitter.com/test</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link

https://jsfiddle.net/Harsh80016/7rku8ao3/

```
var minNumber = 100;
var maxNumber = 40

var randomNumber = randomNumberFromRange(minNumber, maxNumber);

function randomNumberFromRange(min,max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}
```

There is little bit change in your code and I got random number append to your textarea.

Comment: this finishes it, thank you so much: $("#status").append(" " + randomNumber);

Answer (score 0):

It may help

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var randomNum = '',
  numLimitation = "123456789";
 for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  randomNum = randomNum + numLimitation.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * numLimitation.length));
 }
 $('textarea').append(randomNum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="5" cols="50">
test https://twitter.com/test
</textarea>
```

As you have commented this snippet is with `setInterval()` method.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 setInterval(function() {
  var randomNum = '',
   numLimitation = "123456789";
  for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   randomNum = randomNum + numLimitation.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * numLimitation.length));
  }
  $('textarea').text('test https://twitter.com/test' + ' ' + randomNum);
 }, 3000)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="5" cols="100">
  test https://twitter.com/test
</textarea>
```

Comment: yes this works, almost completely, now how to add a blank space automatically before the random number set?

Comment: im curious, any way to use "setInterval(function()" with this?